# How can I avoid a "boot error" when trying to install Fedora 19 from a USB stick

Tags: fedora, boot, system-installation

I am trying to install Fedora 19 on my PC to replace the Fedora 12 I am using now.

I downloaded `Fedora-Live-Desktop-i686-19-1.iso` and did a CHECKSUM test which seemed ok:

```
$ gpg --verify-files /home/Harry/Downloads/*-CHECKSUM.txt
gpg: Signature made Sat 29 Jun 2013 02:05:02 AM BST using RSA key ID FB4B18E6
gpg: Good signature from "Fedora (19) <fedora@fedoraproject.org>"
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: CA81 B2C8 5E4F 4D4A 1A3F  7234 0747 7E65 FB4B 18E6
```

So then I had:

```
/home/Harry/Downloads/Fedora-Live-Desktop-i686-19-1.iso
```

To copy to the USB I used, in `su` mode:

```
liveusb-creator --reset-mbr
```

I use GRUB to boot either Linux or Windows (although the Windows has gone unusable, but I can access the files I need from Linux. Lazily, I have left it like that), so, using F8 to skip the dual boot screen, I chose the USB from the list and got:

```
USB RMD-FDD..OK
Boot error
```

Please I would be grateful for suggestions on how to get out of this impasse.

Comment: I don't understand what's going on completely: are you using GRUB on your hard drive to boot liveUSB? If not and you're using GRUB on USB to boot USB, did you change the device boot priority in BIOS to set USB as primary?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have purchased a Fedora 19 installation disk, and will be using that when I try again. Hopefully there will be no problem with that. Also I am delaying the update for a while, doing plenty of backups, until a long term commitment is completed.

Comment: I was cut off by the five minute rule before I completed that comment. As the question no longer applies I have marked @sim's reply as "accepted", and Bob's comment as "useful". Unfortunately I am allowed only one "notification". Thanks again both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always used [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to do these types of installations. It's a standalone executable so there isn't anything to install, simply download it and run.

[image: ss of unetbootin]

[image: ss of unetbootin]